# handle dynamic class name in factory pattern php

Tags: php, oop, design-patterns

I have multiple provider for send email (`elasticmail` , `mailgun` , ...)

I have a class per provider:

```
class mailgun implement email {

     public function send() {
          // call send api
     }

}

class elasticmail implement email {

     public function send() {
          // call send api
     }

}
```

I create a factory class for make a instance of class

```
class emailFactory {
    public function make($name) {   
        if ($name = 'mailgun')
            return new mailgun();   

        return new elasticmail();
    }
}
```

The problem is that this method is not scalable for add new provider

for example `Ymail` added I Should add this name to Factory class:

```
class emailFactory {
    public function make($name) {   
        if ($name = 'mailgun') {
            return new mailgun();   
        } elseif ($name == 'Ymail') {
            return new Ymail();   
        }

        return new elasticmail();
    }
}
```

how to create a scalable factory class?

Comment: Try asking your question here: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Unless you're going to have a huge number of implementations, the approach you're taking is totally fine. Overengineering is bad

Comment: You could define and use a name -> implementation mapping for slightly cleaner code, it's effectively the same of course.

Answer (score 0):

Using reflection (https://3v4l.org/kF5Dq):

```
<?php

interface Email {
    public function send();
}

class Mailgun implements Email {

     public function send() {
          // call send api
     }

}

class ElasticMail implements Email {

     public function send() {
          // call send api
     }

}

class EmailFactory {
    
    public static function make(string $name) {   
        foreach(get_declared_classes() as $className){
            if ($name == $className && in_array('Email', class_implements($className))) {
                    return new $className();
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}


var_dump(EmailFactory::make('ElasticMail'));
```